# How to check if lambda layer is captured by Keras in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So when I run the code in Keras as below, the model works:

```
def transformer_code(inputLayer):
    hparams = transformer.transformer_base()
    encoder=transformer.TransformerEncoder(hparams,  mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    x = keras.backend.expand_dims(inputLayer, axis=2)
    y = encoder({"inputs": x, "targets": 0, "target_space_id": 0})
    y = keras.backend.squeeze(y[0], 2)
    return y
```

def trainModel(args, trainInput, trianOutput, testInput, testOutput, taskName, tags):

`inputLayer = keras.layers.Input(shape=(len(trainInput[0]),
            len(trainInput[0][0])), dtype='float32')

inputAfterDense = keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(inputLayer)

crfLayer = CRF(len(tags), sparse_target=True, name='result')

y = keras.layers.Lambda(transformer_code)(inputAfterDense )
modelPred = crfLayer(y)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputLayer, outputs=modelPred)
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss = {'result': crfLayer.loss_function},
    metrics={'result': crfLayer.accuracy}
    )
print 'finish model setting'
print model.summary()`

But if I remove the Dense layer

inputAfterDense = keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(inputLayer)

the training breaks and prediction accuracy is nearly zero all the time.

I suspect lambda layer does not get captured by Keras? How do I check?

Comment: What is "captured"? --- If you don't have any layers with trainable parameters, there is nothing to learn.

Comment: So my hypothesis for the code not working is that Lambda layer does not properly add transformer to Keras layers, hence almost zero accuracy. Since I do not have experience with Lambda, I want to know if the above implementation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have resolved your problem by now, but it might be that the Lambda layer is not the most appropriate type of a layer for Transformer. According to the documentation:

> For simple, stateless custom operations, you are probably better off using `layers.core.Lambda` layers. But for any custom operation that has trainable weights, you should implement your own layer.

So you may be better off writing your own Keras layer.